# Subquery containing containstable with a condition from querying table

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, subquery

This query gives me the error:"Incorrect syntax near 'Suggestion'."

```
SELECT(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Products,keywords,Suggestion)) InventoryRank
FROM (
    SELECT Suggestion FROM aTable
)
```

How can I give the same result?

Comment: Does `SELECT Suggestion FROM aTable` return one or multiple rows?

Comment: @wdosanjos:It returns multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONTAINSTABLE cannot work with table column in search condition. You can make it like:

```
DECLARE @search nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @search = STUFF(( 
    SELECT  '*" or "' + Suggestion 
    FROM aTable
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,6,'') +'*"'

--That will give you string like "sug1*" or "sug2*" or "sug3*" to search
--You can make whatever you need string. F.e. "sug1" or "sug2" or "sug3"

SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(searched_table,searched_column,@search)
```

**EDIT**

If you need a different `InventoryRank` per `Suggestion`, you can use dynamic SQL and temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'##temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##temp

CREATE TABLE ##temp (
    Suggestion nvarchar(max),
    InventoryRank int
)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)


SELECT @sql = (
    SELECT N'INSERT INTO ##temp SELECT  '''+Suggestion+''' as Suggestion, COUNT (*) as InventoryRank FROM CONTAINSTABLE(searched_table,searched_column,'''+Suggestion+''');' 
    FROM aTable
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
--PRINT(@sql)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT *
FROM ##temp
```

PRINT will give you query:

```
INSERT INTO ##temp SELECT  'sug1' as Suggestion, COUNT (*) as InventoryRank FROM CONTAINSTABLE(searched_table,searched_column,'sug1');
INSERT INTO ##temp SELECT  'sug2' as Suggestion, COUNT (*) as InventoryRank FROM CONTAINSTABLE(searched_table,searched_column,'sug2');
```

So you do'nt need a WHILE loop or CURSOR to run through all rows from `aTable`

Comment: Thanks, but I need a different `InventoryRank` per Suggestion.

Comment: I add some info, please, take a look :)

Comment: :That works, But a bit slowly, and I'm not sure whether it can handle millions of records or not.Any suggestions? ;)

Comment: Basically full-text is not meant to work with such kind of data (search text that is stored in another table) it is used to build some searches that will work faster than LIKE or any other text-search. I guess you can work directly with full-text index tables, they contain all words in index with some keys, also there is info about how many times some word occurs in main table.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd parameter of `CONTAINSTABLE` must be a literal or variable, it cannot be a column name.  If you need the count of each suggestion, you can try the following:

```
DECLARE @suggestion varchar(100);
DECLARE @result table (Suggestion varchar(100), Result int);
DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR SELECT Suggestion FROM aTable;

FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @suggestion;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result (Suggestion, Result)
        SELECT @suggestion, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Products,keywords,@suggestion));
    FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @suggestion;
END

CLOSE csr;
DEALLOCATE csr;

SELECT * FROM @result;
```

MSDN [CONTAINSTABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) documentation.